# Unable to change directory in Shell Script running on Jenkins

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins

I am trying to run a shell script on Jenkins and want to change the directory. My code is as follows :

```
#!/bin/bash
pwd
function myprog() {
 cd root/data
}

myprog
pwd
```

I tried all possibilities mentioned in the question posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481715/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-shell-script).

I tried symbolic links, Alias and function, however no success. In the jenkins console output i always get the following error :

```
/tmp/hudson772738020072372550.sh: line 11: cd: root/data: No such file or directory
```

What i notice here is that, there is a colon after cd, is that creating some issue? Kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: `myprog` is a confusing name for a function.  Also, using both the `function`  keyword *and* the double parens `()`  is a bashism and not portable to other shells.

Comment: We will need more information about the environment to answer this successfully.

Answer (score 1):

This is the shell's way of saying that the string `root/data`  does not correspond with any directory below the current directory.

You probably meant to say `cd /root/data` instead.

Comment: Hi Henk, thanks for the response. I tried both the ways, (cd root/data as well as cd /root/data) unfortunately none worked. I still get the same error.

Comment: Well, perhaps the directory `/root/data` doesn't exist either?  Occam's Razor.  Create or find a directory that does.  Good luck.

Comment: Hi Henk, the directory exists. I also tried with the existing directories, it didn't work.

Comment: Shell script works under the same user as the slave connected with. Is your slave connected under root?